# Доступ к сайту в локальной сети

Tags: apache, .htaccess, openserver, php

Здраствуйте!  Нужно чтобы мой сайт был доступен в локальной сети **автоматически**. То есть, сайт у меня стоит на флешке со всеми пакетами (движок Open server), и  когда запускаю сервер на каком-либо компьютере хочу чтобы сайт был доступен в локальной сети этого компа. Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне делать или какой движок мне исползовать?   Спасибо..

Comment: он должен быть доступен по ip или по имени?

Comment: по имени, независимо от ip адреса и не изменяя файла hosts

Comment: черт, у меня как раз было предложение по hosts )

Comment: чтобы пользователи сети имели доступ. нужно в каждом компе сети прописать в hosts 
    
    ip-adress mysite.ru

Comment: есть ли другой способ кроме этого?
например, изменить настройки apache или еще что то.

Comment: Условия довольно специфичны.

Comment: виртуалку сделайте там и ее запускайте, адрес по dhcp то что вы хотите не может быть универсальным в принципе.

Comment: VertigoServ и все проблемы решены. Потом в панеле задач он тебе сам напишет ip по которому тебе заходить.

Answer (score 1):

Если он будет в какой-то из любых компьютеров включать каждый раз эту флешку, то IP адрес скорее всего тоже будет меняться (хотя политика компании может быть разная).
И соответственно каждый раз нужно править hosts, так что вариант крайне геморойный.

Более правильным (при таком ТЗ), было бы использовать DNS сервер, в данном случае даже не централизованный, а что-то в роде DynDNS.

Ввключает комп, загружается с флешке веб-сервер и автоматом запускает софт динамического днс, который будет какой-то x домен направлять на фейковую сеть аля 192.168 и.т.д.

Но в идеальном варианте конечно же разместить на статической системе, пусть даже виртуальной системе.
Веб сервисы со статическим контентом такого не любят.

Comment: все. нашел способ в настройках open server. только не по имени а по ip

Comment: вы извращенец